# how to get facebook pageid to get access to likes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Please help me to get step by step in my task.
My task is typical as I think.

I would like to get information if the current user likes my app.

I was googling some days but without final result.

Please point my mistake.

My source (sorry for some garbage):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>

    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="features"></div>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>

        function showFeatures() {
            $("#features")[0].innerHTML = hasFunctions ? 'feauture are available' : 'features are NOT available';       
        }

        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });

                FB.api('/me/likes/PAGEID', function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                });

                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                $("#buttonLogin").hide();
                $("#buttonLike").show();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                $("#status")[0].innerHTML = 'Please log into this app.';
                $("#buttonLogin").show();
                $("#buttonLike").hide();
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                $("#status")[0].innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook';
                $("#buttonLogin").show();
                $("#buttonLike").hide();
            }
            showFeatures();
        }

        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId: MYAPPID,
            status:true,
            cookie : true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
          });

        }

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; //js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APPID";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    </script>

    <div id="buttonLike" class="fb-like" data-href="http://share-box.com" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
    <fb:login-button id="buttonLogin" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">            </fb:login-button>


</body>
</html>
```

As result I have
 - login button and I can login - GOOD

- Like button and I can like/dislike - GOOD
- I can get User info with

`FB.api('/me', function(response)`

- BUT when I try to get like status with

  FB.api('/me/likes/PAGEID', function(response)

I have always empty JSON array [] as response.

PageID I get as 'id' field of a response from

https://graph.facebook.com/MYSITE

Where is my error and how should I act to get like status?

Comment: You will not be able to do that. The user needs to grant user_likes but for your usecase you can't use user_likes so it will not be possible

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for your answer. Please clarify me why I can not use user_like?

Comment: That is only allowed to be used if you enhance the user experience. Like-gating or just showing or not showing the button does not qualify.

Comment: @WizKid Is there a way to solve my task?

Comment: No, there is not. And it is against Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: in some we resources I seen a way to select with FQL a like by user id and page id. They get likes from Facebook. And it is strange to Facebook to give not feature to know if logged-in user has like for a application... Hmmm... Really?

Comment: You can do it if you get user_likes. But you need to follow the requirements for user_likes. You can read about them here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_likes

Comment: Thanking to your help I found some: <fb:login-button id="buttonLogin" scope="public_profile,email,user_likes" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>. So I add user_likes to user's scope. Am I correct? Looks like what I need.

Comment: And then you need to submit your app to Facebook and they will reject it if you don't follow the rules I linked to

Comment: @WizKid Pls make your answer+my info as your answer post. I will check it. Thanks a lot.